# Prove the distributive law holds in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ (modular arithmetic)

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

Would it be enough to assume "$a$ is congruent to $b$ mod $n$", "$c$ is congruent to $d$ mod $n$" and "$f$ is congruent to $g$ mod $n$." Then we would have the equations;

$a = k_1 n + b$

$c = k_2 n + d$

$f = k_3 n + g$

Would I then just show by algebra that;

$a (c + f) = a c + a f$?

Comment: Yes, that would work!

Comment: Is your definition of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ a quotient ring (of equivalence classes), or by congruences?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
a(c+f) &=& (k_1n+b)(k_2n+d+k_3n+e) \\ \\
&=&k_1k_2n^2+k_1nd+k_1k_3n^2+k_1ne+k_2nb+bd+k_3nb+be \\ \\
&=& (k_1k_2n+k_1d+k_1k_3n+k_1e+k_2b+k_3b)n+bd+be \\ \\
&=& k_4n + b(d+e).
\end{eqnarray*}